# Required vim compiled with +python

Tags: python, vim

When I typed in raw and hit `<C-x><C-o>` in a python file, I get the Error:Required vim compiled with +python. But according to the result of command :version, there is a + rather than - in front of python, what should I do to fix this problem?

```
+arabic          +cursorbind      -footer          +mksession       +path_extra      +startuptime     +visual
+autocmd         +cursorshape     +fork()          +modify_fname    -perl            +statusline      +visualextra
-balloon_eval    +dialog_con      +gettext         +mouse           +persistent_undo -sun_workshop    +viminfo
-browse          +diff            -hangul_input    -mouseshape      +postscript      +syntax          +vreplace
++builtin_terms  +digraphs        +iconv           +mouse_dec       +printer         +tag_binary      +wildignore
+byte_offset     -dnd             +insert_expand   -mouse_gpm       +profile         +tag_old_static  +wildmenu
+cindent         -ebcdic          +jumplist        -mouse_jsbterm   +python/dyn      -tag_any_white   +windows
+clientserver    +emacs_tags      +keymap          +mouse_netterm   +python3/dyn     -tcl             +writebackup
+clipboard       +eval            +langmap         +mouse_sgr       +quickfix        +terminfo        +X11
+cmdline_compl   +ex_extra        +libcall         -mouse_sysmouse  +reltime         +termresponse    +xfontset
+cmdline_hist    +extra_search    +linebreak       +mouse_urxvt     +rightleft       +textobjects     -xim
+cmdline_info    +farsi           +lispindent      +mouse_xterm     -ruby            +title           -xsmp
+comments        +file_in_path    +listcmds        +multi_byte      +scrollbind      -toolbar         +xterm_clipboard
+conceal         +find_in_path    +localmap        +multi_lang      +signs           +user_commands   -xterm_save
+cryptv          +float           -lua             -mzscheme        +smartindent     +vertsplit
+cscope          +folding         +menu            +netbeans_intg   -sniff           +virtualedit
```

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem, the accepted answer [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17433/requires-vim-compiled-with-python-2-7-1-or-3-4-support) solved my problem. During the installation of vim through [building from source](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source), you need to execute the configure script with some parameters and the mentioned answer says the `--with-python3-config-dir=` parameter is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 3):

Features marked as [`*/dyn`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#/dyn) may or may not be available. The support for these features is not built in. It depends on the presence of dedicated shared objects.

> To some of the features "/dyn" is added when the          feature is only
>   available when the related library can            be dynamically loaded.

To check if your `vim` can use a dynamic feature, e.g. `python` do:

```
:echo has('python')
```

It will print `0` (false) or `1` (true)

See also [python-dynamic](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#python-dynamic).

**Update:**

If you installed `vim` from source, you will have to rebuild it. Use `--enable-pythoninterp`, `--with-python-config-dir` options. Also make sure you have `python` development headers and libraries installed (`devel` package).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
after I executed `:echo has('python')` in my vim, I get the following errors:
E448: Could not load library function _PyArg_Parse_SizeT
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.

Comment: the python-dynamic is seemingly used on Windows, but I runs vim in Centos 7, and I installed it by the source

Comment: Also. You may have `:echo has('python')`=0 but `:echo has('python3')`=1

Comment: This is the case for me, (has('python') = 0, has('python3')=1) But how do stop the error from showing when I launch nvim on a python file?

Comment: @MichaelDraper were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16.04, after install the plugin, do following to fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome-py2
```